# Can material spell components be reused?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spell-components

Some spells with material components are consumed in some spells, such as the *resurrection* spell.  Most spells with a material component do not claim anything about what happens to their materials after the spell is completed, such as the *true polymorph* spell. Obviously, some material components needed for enhancing weapons, such as the *shillegah* spell, are not consumed. But what happens to the spell components that are not explicitly consumed? Can those components be reused as long as they aren't destroyed(by outside forces, not the spell)?

Comment: I’ve closed this as a duplicate since it has been asked before.